# Sending headers to post request

Tags: python-requests, postman, aws-api-gateway

I have this python code that does not work as expected.

```
import requests
import json

API_ENDPOINT = "https://lkokpdvhc4.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/mycall"

data = {'mnumber':'9819838466'} 
r = requests.post(url = API_ENDPOINT, data = json.dumps(data))

print (r.text)
```

This will return an error:

> {"stackTrace": [["/var/task/index.py", 5, "handler", "return
>   mydic[code]"]], "errorType": "KeyError", "errorMessage": "''"}

When I test the API using Amazon console's gateway, I get the expected output (i.e. string like "mumbai"). It means this is client side issue. I have confirmed this by using "postman" as well that returns the same error as mentioned above. How do I send correct headers to post request?

Comment: Why do you think this is related to headers? Btw you can send headers by `requests.post(url, json=data, headers={xxx: xxx})`. And as you can see if you want to send json you can directly use `json=a_dict_object`.

Comment: Here is the response of the successful execution from AWS console. I expect similar response from python script.  
 https://gist.github.com/shantanuo/a7f24f9e95d5d453142b3113c063f70e

Comment: It looks like you need to add authentication in headers. Have a try? Just pass a `dict` to `headers` parameter as I've commented before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a dictionary with the headers such as

```
 headers = {
            "Authorization": "Bearer 12345",
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "key" : "value"
        }
```

Then at the point of making the request pass it as a keyword argument to the request method i.e `.post()` or `.get()` or `.put`
This will be

```
response = requests.post(API_ENDPOINT, data=json.dumps(data), headers=headers)
```